# Split files on Linux based on patterns

Tags: file, unix, awk, split

Need a quick Linux tip.

I have a file while will have batches with multiple records.

Like

```
123 HDR 098 LLK
blah
blah
blah

456 HDR 098 LLK
blah
blah
blah
789 HDR 098 LLK

blah
blah
blah
```

I need this to be split into multiple files from "HDR"(inclusive) to the next HDR ( non inclusive ).

In this manner if I have 100 batch in the file , I need to split this into 4 files 25 each.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for free coding services, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Show us your code! 
Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '/HDR/{c++} {print > FILENAME"_"c }' file
```

or more generally, to get `n` patterns in a split file, for example for n=3.

```
awk -v n=3 '/HDR/{k=int(c/n)+1; c++} {print > FILENAME"_"k }' file
```

Comment: That's a great ... equal split @karakfa .  I had a hunch awk will come for rescue. How to I extend this to a count of my choice ? say x number of batches in one file.

Comment: It's content dependent, you'll get as many split files as the count of pattern in the file.  Or, may be you're asking something else?

Comment: We are very close. I am asking if we can now group them into say 5 pattern matches and then write to a file. Something like awk '/HDR/{c+5} {print > FILENAME"_"c }' file , as if I am not writing to the splitted file until a certain number of matches are found.

Comment: @karakfa Because there are only a limited number of file descriptors, it might be important to close the last file before doing incrementing `c`.   Also: +1.